# I can't see xrdp screen from second win PC

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, xrdp

I configured vps server and through ssh I installed xrdp and it's working from win 7. now when I connect from another win 7 or win 10 doesnt matter I cant see my work progress on the desktop. When I go back to first pc I can see everything.  It looks like rebooted os but for sure it isn't. Can someone help with this? TNX :)
I tryied on 18.04 and now on 16.04 same thing.

Comment: Lets say I opened one terminal window through remote desktop from win7 and something is working there. And now I want to oconnect from another win7 PC. And when I connect with second PC I don't see terminal window. I can see him only from first PC

Comment: I am using 2 win7 laptops to connect to linux vps server. I opened terminal and 1 program from win7 laptop 1. when I connect to the same linux vps server from win7 laptop 2 I can't see terminal and running program :)

Comment: ...can't see on the terminal ...on laptop 2, right? (keep reminding the object in the sentence so that there's no possible missuderstading, please).

Comment: Connect with laptop 1 (since that one works) and open `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini ` either by typing into a terminal : `sudo nano /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` or for gui `sudo gedit /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` what is the `MaxSessions` value? it's probably too low. Also why use RDP, it's really shit all things considered. use VNC.

Comment: MaxSession is 10
I know vnc is better but I can use only RDP from my work place.

Comment: turn it up to like 50 and do the same in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, make it like this in both files :  `MaxSessions 50`
`MaxStartups 50:30:100`

Comment: still same thing but I installed teamviewer. it works very good with teamviewer. tnx for the help. cheers

Comment: teamviewer's the first thing that came to my mind but then I saw you use RDP and thought you willingly didn't use it....